# What happens when a wall breaker hits a double-layered wall?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I've seen several players making double-walls. I sent a wall-breaker and destroyed both layers. So, my questions are:

If you have a double-layered wall, and a wall-breaker hits it, does the internal wall receive less damage? What if you make a gap of one tile between the two walls? Or do wall-breakers simply do the same damage over some area, regardless of the distance?

In short, how effective are double-walls against wall-breakers?

Comment: added the image, but I'm sure you saw what I meant on the info for the wall breaker by now. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The double layered walls are only "effective" against troops that don't do splash damage. Since the wall breaker does splash damage this makes them almost useless against them, that is unless you do like you said and leave 1 tile of a gap between them since the splash damage on the wall breakers appears to be 1 tile in every direction from the explosion point. This is why you were bypassing those double walls with ease.

[image]

Comment: As I read, I see that pretty much everything is answered.
Although to clarify more, I would like to add [**this**](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Layouts) link here, which describes the how the layout of walls work.
Hope this adds up.

Answer (score 1):

Double layered walls won't do much to stop the wall breaker. The wall breaker is a splash damage troop and can blast through multiple layers of walls. If it can break the first layer than it can break the second layer as well.

Comment: As stated in mine...lol